# How to select coordinate from mysql database

Tags: mysql

I can select column of type 'POINT' using

```
select AsText(column) from mytable;
```

It returns:

```
'POINT(1.2, 3.4)'
```

But can I select it as

```
'1.2, 3.4'
```

?
This can be done in backend (of course) but can mysql convert it for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are special functions like [ST_X, ST_Y](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/gis-point-property-functions.html), e.g.:

```
SELECT
  CONCAT(ST_X(point_column), ', ', ST_Y(point_column))
FROM
  points_table
```